# Magento Search filter not working

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search

Magento Search filter not working at all, although filters on product by category  works fine.
Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
On the search page 
search filters are not working.
sort by is not working
show 6 product not working (it shows more then 6 product)

---

Edit:

When i search of some product it send me to search page
and when i try to filter the search result on the basis of price, category or if i try to sort search result by price, nothing seems to be working..
it just show same number of product in search result.

Comment: Please add more specification regarding what have you tried so far?

Comment: When i search of some product it send me to search page and when i try to filter the search result on the basis of price, category or if i try to sort search result by price, nothing seems to be working.. it just show same number of product in search result
(see the image)

Comment: Please don't post links that might be considered NSFW. You might get people into trouble with that.

Comment: Do you have any caching next to the default Magento cache? Might there be any 3th party modules or changes in the template that might influence this?

Comment: no caching, even the default caching is disabled.
and i will pull back the link in post onces issue is solved.

Comment: Any 3th party modules or template edits?

Comment: yes one the module is installed by me :  InstantSearch+

Comment: Magento search is too bad for user experience .You need to use any third party module...

Comment: @AmitBera yes i am using  InstantSearch+

Comment: Did you contact the developer from InstantSearchplus? It will probably have something to do with the issues. might be an issue with their module.

Comment: i have tried search, disabling  InstantSearch+  nothing seems to work event then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same problem when migrating to 1.9.1.0 with a Templatemonster theme. Fixed it by editing my theme's catalogsearch.xml, around line 62:

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" ##template="page/html/pager/pager.phtml"## />
```

and around line 112

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" ##template="page/html/pager/pager.phtml"## />
```

just remove the code where I the ## and it worked fine for us.

Best luck,

Eduardo